# Bellman Ford Negative Weight - Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have this list of nodes, and I want to get the minimum path, as I have nodes with negative weight would have to use Bellman Ford, I am using networkx library, however I did not get the form to print the path, this is the list of nodes with weights and the command that I am using

```
1 10 {'weight': 96}
1 13 {'weight': 97}
2 11 {'weight': -70}
2 13 {'weight': 77}
3 12 {'weight': 30}
3 13 {'weight': -30}
4 10 {'weight': 17}
4 14 {'weight': -75}
5 11 {'weight': -4}
5 14 {'weight': 45}
6 12 {'weight': -67}
6 14 {'weight': 63}
7 10 {'weight': 38}
7 15 {'weight': -40}
8 11 {'weight': -30}
8 15 {'weight': -46}
9 12 {'weight': 37}
9 15 {'weight': -97}




assert_raises(nx.NetworkXUnbounded,nx.bellman_ford,G_Bellman_Ford,1)
```

Where G_Bellman_Ford is the graph

Comment: That looks like a list of edges with weights.  Are those edges part of a graph or digraph (directed)?  If it is a graph there is probably a negative edge cycle.

Comment: They are part of a digraph

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: edges ="""1 10 {'weight': 96}
1 13 {'weight': 97}
2 11 {'weight': -70}
2 13 {'weight': 77}
3 12 {'weight': 30}
3 13 {'weight': -30}
4 10 {'weight': 17}
4 14 {'weight': -75}
5 11 {'weight': -4}
5 14 {'weight': 45}
6 12 {'weight': -67}
6 14 {'weight': 63}
7 10 {'weight': 38}
7 15 {'weight': -40}
8 11 {'weight': -30}
8 15 {'weight': -46}
9 12 {'weight': 37}
9 15 {'weight': -97}"""

In [3]: lines = edges.split('\n')

In [4]: G = nx.parse_edgelist(lines, nodetype = int, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

In [5]: nx.bellman_ford(G,1)
Out[5]: ({1: None, 10: 1, 13: 1}, {1: 0, 10: 96, 13: 97})
```

Comment: but it is only returning the weights of the neighboring nodes

Comment: The first element of the tuple is a dictionary of predecessors and the second is a dictionary of distances.  E.g. the path from 1->10 is one hop with weight 96.

Answer (score 0):

> For your question, to print the path from nx.bellman_ford(), just follow the answer from Aric, but update last statement.

```
pred, dist = nx.bellman_ford(G,1)
```

Define function to convert return predecessors to path

```
def predecessors_to_path(pred, source, target):
    path = []
    curr = target
    while curr != source:
        path.append(curr)
        curr = pred[curr]
    path.append(source)
    path.reverse()
    return path
```

> To get your path form, just convert format

```
>>> print(predecessors_to_path(pred,1,10))
[1, 10]
```